# Proving that the statement $f: X \to Y$ is continuous iff $x_n \to x \implies$ $f(x_n) \to f(x)$ maybe false if $X,$ and $Y$ are not metric spaces.

Tags: general-topology, contest-math

Given that $f: (X, \tau_1) \to (X, \tau_2)$ is a map. Then I want to show that even if $x_n \to x \implies f(x_n) \to f(x),$ f may not be continuous.

I know that f is continuous if $(X, \tau_1)$ is first countable. So I must not have $\tau_1$ to be first countable.
But I can not find such f and $(X,\tau_1)$

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: @DarthLubinus then the function will be continuous and we want a function which is not continuous but satisfies the limit condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sketch: Let $X=\Bbb R$, and let $\tau_1$ be the co-countable topology: $U\subseteq X$ is open iff $U=\varnothing$, or $X\setminus U$ is countable. Let $\tau_2$ be the discrete topology, and let $f$ be the identity map. Prove that $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ have the same convergent sequences, but that $f$ is not continuous.